# Unable to load library using ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom

Tags: oracle, powershell, reflection

Well... I ´m having a problem with an 3rd party application that needs to connect to an Oracle Database. The problem is that 'Oracle.DataAccess' library is not being able to load.

The manufacturer told me to run the following command in powershell:

```
$path="D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom($path).ImageRuntimeVersion
```

And that is supposed to return the framework version that is being used. That does not work and throws the following message:

```
Exception calling "ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not loa d file or assembly 'file:///D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4\Ora cle.DataAccess.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a run time newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded." At line:1 char:46
+ [Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom <<<< ($path).ImageRuntimeVersio n
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

This server is running W2008 Server R2. The weird thing is that on another machine I have running W2012 Server the thing works just fine.
I´ve already installed and repair all possible .net framework versions.

Can someone help me on this one?.

Comment: Check `$psversiontable`, and pay particular attention to `CLRVersion`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the CLRVersion is 2.0.50727.8762

Comment: Well, that would explain why you can't load a .NET 4 assembly, as that uses CLR version 4. If you haven't yet upgraded PowerShell and it's still stuck on PowerShell 2.0 (the default of Windows 2008 R2), consider upgrading (we are at 5.1 already, and 6.0 is being worked on). I'm not sure if it's possible to make PowerShell 2.0 use the v4 CLR, but casual searches suggest it's not possible to do cleanly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i will try that and let you know

Comment: @JeroenMostert You were just right. I updated and now it works. If you want to answer you will be accepted. Thanks!